# MySql query to get all user's conversations and data about user that he is having conversation with

Tags: javascript, mysql

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvOfX.png)
I am creating simple conversation app. I have three tables - users(id,name), conversations(id,user1_id, user2_id) and messages (id,conversationId,sender,message,date). Is there a way to actually get all user's conversations and data about another user in one query?

The query below gets id's of the user that logged user  has conversations with. I would like now to get these users data base on their id. Thanks for all suggestions.

```
const getChats = (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  db.query(
"SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN user1_id = ? THEN user2_id ELSE user1_id END userID FROM conversations WHERE ? IN (user2_id , user1_id)",
    [userId, userId],
    (e, r) => {
      res.send(r);
    }
  );
};

module.exports = { getChats };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll answer the second question "how can get rid of doubling conversations where only conversation id differs and users are basically swapped?" to resolve this issue you need to check the conversation table before insertion by the below query

```
db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM conversations WHERE (user1_id = ? AND user2_id = ?) OR (user1_id = ? AND user2_id = ?)",
    [senderId, receiverId,receiverId,senderId],
    (e, r) => {
      res.send(r);
    }
  );
```

if the above query returns a record then we'll not insert a new row.

now query for message with user data of a conversation

```
db.query(
    "SELECT m.*,c.id,
            s.name as "SenderUserName",
            r.name as "ReceiverUserName",
     FROM messages m 
     inner join conversations c on m.conversationId = c.id 
     inner join user r on r.id = c.user1_id
     inner join user s on s.id = c.user2_id
     WHERE (c.user1_id = ? AND c.user2_id = ?) OR (c.user1_id = ? AND 
     c.user2_id = ?)",
    [senderId, receiverId,receiverId,senderId],
    (e, r) => {
      res.send(r);
    }
  );
```

the above query will return all messages between 2 users.
though you can remove the conservations table from the structure and it will be easy approach, here is the structure that i suggest

users table

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| name | varchar |

messages table

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| message | text |
| sender_id | int |
| receiver_id | int |
| created_at | timestamp |

Comment: Thank you for your help but your answer doesn't rly match my db structure.

Comment: as per your shared image of the database structure, the above queries are meant for that structure, please let me know what makes an issue. thanks

Comment: i believe that there is no receiver column in the structure which i shared

Comment: but I didn't use the receiver as a column in the query. the only places where receiver is mentioned are alias. They'll work fine on the structure without an error. you can try it.

Comment: but what if I don't have receiver_id? the only parameter that I got is userId which belongs to logged user

Comment: ok then replace this line
 
` WHERE (c.user1_id = ? AND c.user2_id = ?) OR (c.user1_id = ? AND  c.user2_id = ?)` 

with
 
` WHERE c.user1_id = ? OR c.user2_id = ?`

and replace the parameter with [userId, userId]
then you will all the messages of a user with multiple conversations

Comment: and this one "how can get rid of doubling conversations where only conversation id differs and users are basically swapped?" comes again...

Comment: for that, you have to check before inserting it in the conversations table. the query in the answer handles this issue

Comment: that is why I suggested removing the conversations table from the structure because it doesn't do anything you can easily get a DISTINCT number conversation of the user from the messages table that I suggested and you don't have to check before inserting the massage table.

Comment: the only case where you will need the conversation table is a group chat feature but structure of that table going to be totally different from your conversation table